# Azure web app giving HTTP error 500 when viewed, how can this be fixed?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

trying to upload my mobile web application to azure
followed
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode

ended up just getting the error unable to handle request HTTP error 500

the web app works locally so i dont know what the issue is
a friend told me it was might be because all webpages in the views folder are .ejs files when they should be HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the same document which you have provided and able to access the Application without any issues.

- Create `Node.js` Application using the below command.

```cs
npx express-generator myExpApp19Dec --view ejs
```

[image]

- Navigate to the Application root directory(`myExpApp19Dec`) and run `npm install`.

[image]

- `node_modules` folder will be created at root of the directory.
- Run `npm start` to start and run the application in local.

[image]

[image]

- Open the Application from VSCode.

***Steps to deploy Web App to Azure App Service***

- Sign into `Azure` => Click on `Azure Icon` => Select your `Subscription` = > `App Services`.

[image]

```cs
web app name - ExpressApp19Dec
runtime stack - Node 18 LTS
OS - Windows
Location - East US
```

[image]

- Immediately after deployment, when I tried to access the Application, I got the below error.
  [image]
- Added `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` in Application Setting as suggested in the document.
- Navigate to the deployed App folder in `VSCode` => Your `App` => `Application Settings` =>`Add New Setting`.

[image]

- We can even add this `Application Setting` from `Azure Portal` => `App Service` => `Configuration` section. Re-deploy option can be excluded when we add `Application Setting` from Azure Portal.

[image]

- Re-deploy the Application to get the latest changes.

[image]

- Make sure `web.config` file is created at the root directory of the deployed Application in `KUDU` Console.

Path to KUDU Console -
***`https://YourAppServiceName.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`***

[image]

***My autogenerated`web.config` file***

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>   
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>     
      <add name="iisnode" path="bin/www" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>      
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^bin/www\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>
       
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{PATH_INFO}"/>
        </rule>       
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="bin/www"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>   
   
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>  
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />     
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

- Now Iam able to access the Application.

[image]

> all webpages in the views folder are .ejs files when they should be HTML.

- In `VSCode` => `root folder` => `app.js` file,

```cs
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

[image]

This code helps to detect the `ejs` files. The issue is not with the `ejs` files.

`EJS` is an `Embedded JavaScript` template which is used by Node JS Application.